# No Push messages received on iOS device

Tags: ios, push

I have integrated the iOS SDK in our native iOS app. Everything looking fine initially, i was receiving Push messages (sandbox environment) in testing phase. 
All of sudden, I Stopped receiving push messages from their portal anymore.
Everything looks good in console/SDK logs.  No errors/warnings at all. Still when i send Push Messages from exact-target portal, they are showing as successfully sent but never received on iOS Device. 
At the same time if i use any third party (like pushtry), i am able to receive the push.
Any idea, what may be the possible issue ?

Answer (score 1):

@Asp have you checked the APNS push certificate to ensure it is still valid and confirmed that the one added to the MarketingCloud account has not expired?

Also, it would be worth confirming that the ETPush configuration is returning successfully. Are you using our latest SDK (v 4.8.0)? See http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/

Brian Criscuolo
Salesforce